# Is Angular2 (rc2) content now more indexable by Google?

Tags: angular

AngularJS(1) needed some help from a tool like PhantomJS to make content readable and indexable by Google.

Now with Angular2, is content more naturally indexable without worrying about having to use a special process/tool to render content?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914371/angular2-seo-how-to-make-an-angular-2-app-crawlable. (which is also an older post). This is more of a philosophical Angular2 question and trying to see how well it can be indexed withtout 3rd party plug-ins like "Universal".

Comment: Then you should add other tags. How well search engines index dynamically created sites is not Angular related. Philosophical questions are generally discouraged at SO.

Comment: Thank you Günter for your comment. It answers my question at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if Angular development and Google seem somehow related, it appears that the answer, as of June 2016, is no. There are no special signs that Google reads more effectively Angular2 generated content vs AngularJS(1) content.