# Are SEO problems in angularJs fixed in angular 2.0.0? And how?

Tags: angular, seo

Are all routes indexable by google Analytics with no issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 SEO - How to make an angular 2 app crawlable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914371/angular2-seo-how-to-make-an-angular-2-app-crawlable)