# Angular.js github pages SEO

Tags: angularjs, github, seo, single-page-application, github-pages

I have created very simple portfolio website using Angular.js, and I'm hosting it on GitHub Pages. I use Angular.js because I'd like it to have a SPA feeling. It contains mostly images, as it is an artist portfolio app, but also it contains a description page with text, which is (probably) not crawled by Google bot.

Is there a way to SEO my Angular.js website, when it's hosted in static website hosting like GitHub Pages? I've read about prerender, but it's a server-side tool, which can't work on GitHub Pages. I don't control server side (GitHub Pages doesn't allow that). So I cant use anything like server-side rendering.

I use some seo-friendly markup in my index.html file, like meta title with words of value for me, description, etc., but I'm afraid this is not enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 SEO - How to make an angular 2 app crawlable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914371/angular2-seo-how-to-make-an-angular-2-app-crawlable)

Comment: I don't think what I ask is a duplicate of what you pasted, as my problem is that I don't control server side (github pages doesn't allow that). So I cant use anything like server-side rendering.

Comment: This might not be the answer you're looking for, however if you're targeting Google you might not need a prerender service since googlebot started crawling JS. https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/12/rendering-ajax-crawling-pages.html